# Iterating vectors python 2.7

Tags: python

I need to get the values ​​of the positions of the vectors to be able to visualize them.

I have two vectors

```
a = [15, 10, 7 , 1, 12, 16]
b = [11, 7, 18, 2, 10, 2]
```

And I need to get position one of vector a and position one of vector b, then position 2 of vector a and position 2 of vector and so on

I was using a nested form but it does not work as I require it

```
for x in a:
   for y in b:
      print x,y
```

this print

```
15,11
15,7
15,18
15,2
15,10
15,2
10,11
10,7.....
```

but i need it to print

```
15, 11
10, 7
7, 18
1, 2
12, 10
16, 2
```

Comment: Those are called lists not vectors

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip`.

```
>>> a = [15, 10, 7 , 1, 12, 16]
>>> b = [11, 7, 18, 2, 10, 2]
>>> for x,y in zip(a,b):
...     print(x,y)
...
15 11
10 7
7 18
1 2
12 10
16 2
```